# Setting Tooltip for TableColumn in FXML

Tags: javafx, tooltip, fxml

For a `Button`, I can set a Tooltip via

```
<Button>
    <tooltip>
        <Tooltip text="Tooltip text" />
    </tooltip>
</Button>
```

How can I do the same/ similar for a `TableColumn`?

```
<TableColumn>
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="someProperty" />
    </cellValueFactory>
    <tooltip>
        <Tooltip text="Tooltip text" />
    </tooltip>
</TableColumn>
```

Does not work..

Comment: What do you want this to do? Set the tooltip on the column header (which is actually quite tricky), or set the tooltip on the cells in the column? (Neither of these can be done in FXML; you have to do them in the controller.)

Comment: Good question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a tooltip on the column header, one way is to set a graphic on the `TableColumn` instead of setting text, and to set the tooltip on the graphic.

I.e. instead of:

```xml
<TableColumn text="Column 1">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="someProperty" />
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

you can do

```xml
<TableColumn>
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="someProperty" />
    </cellValueFactory>
    <graphic>
        <Label text="Column 1">
            <tooltip>
                <Tooltip text="Tooltip text" />
            </tooltip>
        </Label>
    </graphic>
</TableColumn>
```

Note that this has some side-effects. For example, the table view has a [menu button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#tableMenuButtonVisibleProperty) that controls the visibility of the columns. This is populated by menu items whose text is the text of the column: so using this technique will make that menu button unusable. Creating a table column with a tooltip while preserving the table column's `text` value requires some CSS hackery.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations! Actually I just want to provide some further information on the Column Header text, which is rather short to save space. So yes, I guess I want to set a Tool Tip for the Column Header. Your approach will replace the column header text set before? Do you know why there is no direct way to do this?

Comment: There's no direct way to do it because `TableColumn` is not a `Node`. The motivation for this is that the column is considered part of the table view's data model, rather than its actual view (though this idea is somewhat destroyed by having a `graphic` property: there should be a `headerCellFactory` or something similar). Since it's not a node, there's no tooltip. This approach will replace the text with a label; so you set the label's text to the text you want displayed. Now you have a reference to the label that is used as the graphic, so you can set a tooltip on it.